# Bizarre log4j error

Tags: java, maven, log4j, jms

Trying to use log4j's built-in JMSAppender to log messages to a local message queue (ActiveMQ).

I set up a test `Driver` that has an entry `main` method and that just instantiates the actual class I want to make the connection:

`Driver.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Log4jAmqBridge bridge = new Log4jAmqBridge();
    bridge.run();
}
```

`Log4jAmqBridge.java`:

```
public void run() {
    // ...
}
```

If I leave my `run` method totally empty (no instructions) and run the `Driver`, I just get an empty console (Eclipse). But the second I add the following constructor to `run()`:

```
JMSAppender appender = new JMSAppender();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
    at test.jmsappender.Log4jAmqBridge.run(Log4jAmqBridge.java:11)
    at test.Driver.main(Driver.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I checked the [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.html) and it doesn't look like the `JMSAppender` no-arg constructor throws an exception.

Does anybody know whats going on?

**Edit**:
I am actually using Maven to manage my dependencies and have included the following dependency declarations in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Which puts the following jars under the Maven Dependencies in my project (which are also added to the Eclipse workbench classpath):

- slf4j-api-1.6.4
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4
- log4j-1.2.16

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your classpath for conflicting jars

Comment: You're missing either that class, or something that depends on it. What are you deploying? What are you deploying to? What are you using for JMS?

Comment: Please see my edit about Maven & dependencies...

Comment: A missing class is not bizarre...fairly common in fact.  Try running your code outside of Eclipse - that will at least remove your Eclipse configuration as a source of the error.

Comment: So, what are you using for JMS?

Comment: Hi Dave - I'm using the code snippet that @nico_ekito suggested I use. Please not that I am not getting another error related to this dependency declaration (I wrote a comment underneath his/her answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4jAmqBridge depends on the JMS API.

Add this dependency to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks nico_ekito, but when I put that into my `<dependencies>` element, I get the following error: `Missing artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1`. This error shows up in Eclipse as a highlighted error. If I try to run the the code anyways I get the same error...

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, I was under the impression that any packages beginning with `java.*` or `javax.*` came with the JDK/JRE. Why do I need to declare this dependency (even once I get it working) since its clearly a Java component?

Comment: This one is a JEE dependency, it is not in the JSE (standard JDK). Try this dependency for JMS : <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thanks again nico_ekito - this one worked! Any ideas as to why? What can I do to get your first suggestion (javax.jms) working? If I had my druthers, I'd rather use a reference implementation of JMS than the Geronimo one.

Comment: I don't know why the first one did not worked. If you do not want to use Geronimo, don't forget to change the dependency to the JMS provider you'll use (ActiveMQ or else).